# How to Change the www root directory on WampServer 3

Tags: php, apache, wamp

How can i change the root directory of the currently installed wampserver to some other directory.
I have change directory location from httpd.conf
like.
I am using Hash tag before Dcoument root, and Directory but for new root i have new line without hash tag.

```
#DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www"
DocumentRoot "G:/04-WebSites/NEW_WORK"
#<Directory "c:/wamp64/www/">
<Directory "G:/04-WebSites/NEW_WORK/">
```

C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.18\conf\httpd.conf

after many time restart server, pc, wamp server still showing www/index page.

[image: index page is shown]

Comment: Dont change those values. Instead create a virtual host for each of your projects

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to change these values also in httpd-vhosts.conf located in \conf\extra

Comment: Note that if your path contains spaces, eg: `g:/Google Drive/`, you will need to use double quotes `" "` in both lines.

Comment: Thank you. This is the only place I've seen this. Every other how-to for this only says to change the folder locations in httpd.conf and that wasn't working for me.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open wampserver 3 .
2. Select the Apache menu  -> httpd-vhosts.conf.
3. Change the DocumentRoot path --> "${INSTALL_DIR}/www" to your folder location e.g. "E:/www"
4. Restart the Wampserver
5. Done.

For detail blog go here : https://phantomthemes.com/how-to-change-the-www-root-directory-on-wampserver-3/

let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please just note if you want to promote or recommend your own product/blog, there are some [guidelines in place](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) for doing so. Following them will help you avoid giving the impression that you're spamming. Could you please [edit] to explicitly state your affiliation? Thanks. (If you're not actually affiliated, it may be worth mentioning that as well.)

Comment: This was not the solution for me. In my case, I had just deleted/unmounted `Y:` drive, which was mapped to a shared folder in a VirtualBox Win7Ultimate machine. That was the cause of Wampserver staying orange and not turning green. After much troubleshooting and research, I realized that VB or Win automatically changed my `W:` drive to `X:` after I deleted Y:. Weird. But, changing the appropriate folder values in `httpd-vhosts.conf` solved it. Restart all services also.